# How to add devices from storyboard View as

Tags: xcode, storyboard

[image]

This is my storyboard screen.

As you see, There are 4 iPhone type in my Xcode.

I want to add an iPad here. But, I don't know how to add other devices.

Comment: I create a new storyboard, There are all the devices!!!!


Does it have the option to change the storyboard's settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved.

Go to 'Interface Builder Document' then check the 'Use Trait Variations'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first check, might be your app is iPhone only.Select universal app first.

[image]